# Index of multidimensional array

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, indexing, scipy

I have a problem using multi-dimensional vectors as indices for multi-dimensional vectors. Say I have C.ndim == idx.shape[0], then I want C[idx] to give me a single element. Allow me to explain with a simple example:

```
A = arange(0,10)
B = 10+A
C = array([A.T, B.T])
C = C.T
idx = array([3,1])
```

Now, C[3] gives me the third row, and C[1] gives me the first row. C[idx] then will give me a vstack of both rows. However, I need to get C[3,1]. How would I achieve that given arrays C, idx?

/edit: 
An answer suggested tuple(idx). This work's perfectly for a single idx. But: 
Let's take it to the next level: say INDICES is a vector where I have stacked vertically arrays of shape idx. tuple(INDICES) will give me one long tuple, so C[tuple(INDICES)] won't work. Is there a clean way of doing this or will I need to iterate over the rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you convert `idx` to a `tuple`, it'll be interpreted as basic and not advanced indexing:

```
>>> C[3,1]
13
>>> C[tuple(idx)]
13
```

For the vector case:

```
>>> idx
array([[3, 1],
       [7, 0]])
>>> C[3,1], C[7,0]
(13, 7)
>>> C[tuple(idx.T)]
array([13,  7])
>>> C[idx[:,0], idx[:,1]]
array([13,  7])
```

Comment: Perfect. Let's take it to the next level: say INDICES is a vector where I have stacked vertically arrays of shape idx. tuple(INDICES) will give me one long tuple, so C[tuple(INDICES)] won't work. Is there a clean way of doing this or will I need to iterate over the rows?

Comment: `C[INDICES[0], INDICES[1]]` will do what you describe, as will `C[tuple(INDICES.T)]`.

Comment: I was going to recommend `tuple(INDICES.T)`.  Wouldn't it need to be `C[INDICES[:,0], INDICES[:,1]]`, though?  Or am I transposing things in my head incorrectly, like always?

Comment: Yes, I think you are right, my two answers are definitely not consistent, and the second seems to be the one thats right.

Comment: As Jaime says, every *row* conincides with one set of indices. So INCIDES[0],... is correct. However, tuple(INDICES.T) gives me a tuple of 2 elements, containing N items (where N is the number of rows). C[tuple(INCIDES.T) then gives IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type

On the other hand, tuple(x) gives me N "subtuples" of 2 indices, which is correct so far (I guess). However, C[tuple(x)] will give me IndexError: too many indices.

Comment: "set of indices" is ambiguous -- does each row contain the full coordinates for a specific element, or all of the 0-coordinates?  The above seems to work for me.

Comment: Every row contains the full coordinates.

Comment: Then I'm very surprised that the above didn't work -- I copied and pasted the transcript directly.